# get all country names with their state and region code

Tags: magento2, country-regions

Here is my Magento code:

```
private function getAllCountry() {

    require_once("../app/Mage.php");
    umask(0);
    Mage::app("default");

    $countryName = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load('FR')->getName(); //get country name

    echo 'Country Name ->'.$countryName.'<br/>';

    $states = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load('FR')->getRegions();//state names

    foreach ($states as $state)
    {
        echo 'ID->'.$state->getId().'<br/>';
        echo 'Name->'.$state->getName().'<br/>';

    }
}
```

I want to get the list of all country names with their states and region id in an array.

Answer (score 14):

Note that although these answers might work, they're not the proper *Magento Way*™ to do this. The right path to choose is to use Service Contract.

The Directory module comes with a very handy Service Contract called the *"CountryInformationAcquirerInterface"*. You can find it at `Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface`. This has a very handy function called `getCountriesInfo()`, which returns an array of `CountryInformation` data models, which - in their turn - have a method called `getAvailableRegions()`. So the full example would look something like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface
 */
protected $countryInformationAcquirer;

/**
 * Constructor call.
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformationAcquirer
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformationAcquirer
) {
    $this->countryInformationAcquirer = $countryInformationAcquirer;
}

/**
 * Just a simple example
 * @return array
 */
public function example()
{
    $data = [];

    $countries = $this->countryInformationAcquirer->getCountriesInfo();

    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        // Get regions for this country:
        $regions = [];

        if ($availableRegions = $country->getAvailableRegions()) {
            foreach ($availableRegions as $region) {
                $regions[] = [
                    'id'   => $region->getId(),
                    'code' => $region->getCode(),
                    'name' => $region->getName()
                ];
            }
        }

        // Add to data:
        $data[] = [
            'value'   => $country->getTwoLetterAbbreviation(),
            'label'   => __($country->getFullNameLocale()),
            'regions' => $regions
        ];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

With most tasks in Magento 2, the best approach is to check first if there's a Service Contract that might fit your needs. Because most of the time, there is.

Comment: Are there any "restriction" not to use API/Service Contracts?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware of. It's even more reliable: if the service contract has an `@api`-annotation, it's guaranteed to be backward compatible (see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/api-concepts.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/contributor-guide/backward-compatible-development/). The only "restriction" I can think of is DI: since you depend on abstractions you don't know the explicit implementation. But then again: the whole idea of interfaces is that you should not need to care about this. If you do care about this, you probably have a code smell.

Comment: I like this, but it only returns the countries enabled for the current store (which normally would be fine), but in this case I'd like every country. Is there a way to do that with this Service Contract?

Answer (score 9):

Try this for Magento2. It will return an multi array with country's and there regions if available.

```
$countryHelper = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country'); 
$countryFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory');

$countries = $countryHelper->toOptionArray(); //Load an array of countries

    foreach ( $countries as $countryKey => $country ) {

        if ( $country['value'] != '' ) { //Ignore the first (empty) value

            $stateArray = $countryFactory->create()->setId(
                $country['value']
            )->getLoadedRegionCollection()->toOptionArray(); //Get all regions for the given ISO country code

            if ( count($stateArray) > 0 ) { //Again ignore empty values
                $countries[$countryKey]['states'] = $stateArray;
            }

        }
    }

var_dump($countries);
```

*STAND ALONE VERSION*

Add the code below to a file 'test.php' in your magento root directory and navigate to it from a web browser.  By no means should you attempt to use objectmanager directly inside of a controller, but outside of magento, this is the 'approved' way of getting to it.

```
<?php


use Magento\Framework\AppInterface;

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Autoload error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
try {
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $countryHelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country');
    $countryFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory');
    $countryCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection');

$items = $countryCollection->loadByStore(null);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    var_dump($item->getData());
}

$countries = $countryHelper->toOptionArray(); //Load an array of countries
foreach ( $countries as $countryKey => $country ) {


if ( $country['value'] != '' ) { //Ignore the first (empty) value

            $stateArray = $countryFactory->create()->setId(
                $country['value']
            )->getLoadedRegionCollection()->toOptionArray(); //Get all regions for the given ISO country code

            if ( count($stateArray) > 0 ) { //Again ignore empty values
                $countries[$countryKey]['states'] = $stateArray;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please update your answer with an explanation of what the code does and how it will solve the OP's problem.

Comment: This code works perfectly. I suppose its a prerequisite you need to understand magento dependency injection in order to get it to work.  It returns an array of the countries, and regions.

Comment: Where is the state man!

Answer (score 3):

Done in two files:

**Template File:**

```
<select name="countries">
    <option class="placeholder" value="" disabled selected>Country</option>
    <?php 
        $countries = $block->getAvailableCountries();
        foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country->getCountryId(); ?>"><?php echo $country->getName(); ?></option>
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

**Block File:**

```
use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory as CountryCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Catalogue extends Template
{

    protected $_countryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CountryCollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getAvailableCountries()
    {
        $collection = $this->_countryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*');

        return $collection;
    }

}
```